# Cookie in response header is not set in browser cookie store

Tags: scala, cookies, graphql, playframework, sangria

I'm using the scala play framework and graphql. I'm trying to set the cookie on graphql mutation by following this blog - https://sysgears.com/articles/best-practices-for-processing-http-headers-and-cookies-in-a-scala-graphql-api/
I'm able to see the cookie in the response headers in the browser as well as in postman client, but it is not set in the browser cookie store.
Below is the snap of response headers. Am I missing something here ?

[image]

Update: Tried on chrome-Version 98.0.4758.102 (Official Build) (64-bit), Firefox 97.0 (64-bit) and Brave Version 1.35.103 Chromium: 98.0.4758.102 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: On which domain is the cookie dropped and which domain are you using through your browser?

Comment: @GaëlJ All the setup is on the localhost as of now. My backend code is running on loalhost:8080, which is responsible for setting the cookie. And I'm searching in the same domain.

Answer (score -1):

[If the HttpOnly flag (optional) is included in the HTTP response header, the cookie cannot be accessed through client side script (again if the browser supports this flag).](https://owasp.org/www-community/HttpOnly)